# Custom html tags on page render skip HTML parsing for some reason

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, custom-element, html5-template

I don't know, why it's happening, but looks like custom html tags cannot parse it's content properly on page load if there's really a lot of such elements.

```
document.registerElement('x-tag', 
  {
    prototype: Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
      attachedCallback: { value: function() {
        console.log(this.innerHTML, this.childNodes); // wrong innerHTML and childNodes once in n-occurrences 
      } 
    }})
  }
);
```

Here's [an example](http://codepen.io/align_the_a/pen/jMgdbM)

My hypothesis is that there's some kind of stack, and sometimes this stack just overflows :)

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it? 
(I'm already looking under the hood of react fiber.. to get the scheduling from there).

Comment: @Supersharp looks like it's chrome-related issue.
btw, what browser do you use?

Comment: also on Opera but it's the same <blink> engine :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the elements are added to the DOM tree as they are parsed.

Here the document is very large, so elements are not added in a single pass but in several chunks. Sometimes only 1 or 2 elements are added (at the end of the chunk) and then the Custom Element is created and attached whith a piece of its definitive child nodes only.

To fix it, you can define the custom element only after all the document is parsed. Put the `<script>` after the `<x-tag>s`, or use the `onload` event.

```
document.onload = function ()
{
    document.registerElement('x-tag', { prototype: proto } )
}
```

---

Else if for some reasons the Custom Element is already defined, put the numerous tags in a `<template>` element, then insert its `content` in a single operation:

```
<template id=tpl>
  <x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag><x-tag></x-tag>...
</template> 
<script>
    target.appendChild( document.importNode( tpl.content, true )
</script>
```

Comment: "elements are not added in a single pass but in several chunks" looks like that's the problem, but only appears in chrome for some reason (ff, safari have no such issue). what do you mean by the second part of your answer?   
change the inner html of <x-tag> to: <x-tag><template>... ?

Comment: FF and Safari don't implement Custom Elements. And if you use the polyfill i think it waits for the onload event. I updated my answer.

Comment: oh, looks like it